# How to prove that you've been living outside a country during a period?

Tags: taxes, netherlands

I need to prove that I've been residing outside the Netherlands for a period of 24 months in order to apply for the ["30%-ruling"](http://tax-consultants-international.com/read/30_percent_regulation_netherla#6).

Some suggestions I got were:

- Payslips
- Registration on a city hall
- Declaration of leave provided by you to a government

What other ways would there be?

Comment: Bank account statements showing housing and routine living expenses in a different location, and none in the Netherlands.

Comment: Where have you seen this recommendation? It does not seem to appear on the website you mentioned nor on the official belastingdienst website...

Comment: Proving you lived outside of the Netherlands is easy enough, registration is mandatory there and you can get an "Uittreksel uit de basisregistratie personen" that shows when you were not registered in the Netherlands. What's a bit more difficult is that you also need to prove you lived further than 150 km away from the border.

Comment: @Gala I got these suggestions from a person helping me apply, not an official source.